# How to add different style page numbers in Libreoffice writer?

Tags: libreoffice

I want to have roman page numbers(i, ii) to first two pages and numerical page numbers(1,2,3,4...) to all other pages in a document.

[This](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Page_Numbers#Using_Different_Page_Number_Styles) wiki seems to provide a solution, but I have tried it many times in many ways but still I get either all numbers or all roman numbers.

This is what I tried,

- click on page 1. press <kbd>F11</kbd> and click on first page from page styles section.
- click on page 2. press <kbd>F11</kbd> and click on first page from page styles section.
- Add roman number style page numbers to page 1. **This gets added to all pages**.
- Add  numerical style page numbers to page 3. **This gets added to all pages**.

Can you provide a working solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two page styles Style1 and Style2, one with Roman page numbers and one with numerical page numbers. Set the first pages to Style1. Right-click on the first paragraph of the second section and choose "Paragraph...". Click the "Text Flow" tab. In the "Line end" section, check the "Insert" box and the "with page style:" box. From the drop down list, choose Style2.

Comment: This answer almost works. So I decided to have first 4 pages in roman and then all arabic. I get first 4 pages roman. But then for next pages, instead of starting from 1,2,3... it starts from the actual page count, i.e 5,6,7.... How do I get it to start from 1,2,3....

Comment: That is easy: Menu: Insert > Field > Others > First tab (Document) > select Type = page > select Select = Page Number > Offset (bottom right). If you enter -4, your 5th document page will get the page number 1.

Answer (score 0):

The two different pages must be of different style.
This means that (e.g.) you must insert a manual page break (Insert --> Manual Break --> page break) and select a different style than the one applied to the first page. Then you can proceed as you describe.