# LibreOffice: Page number start on 5th page, also remove footer for first 4 pages

Tags: libreoffice

[No page number in first page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101838/no-page-number-in-first-page)

The link above ain't working. My document has 25 pages and I need page 5 to start as page 1, with the preceding pages not having any pages numbers. I would also like to remove the footer for the first 5 pages.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but this question handles a similar case: http://askubuntu.com/questions/610388/how-to-add-different-style-page-numbers-in-libreoffice-writer/ including (in the comments) the trick of resetting the page number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created two page styles.

Then from the context menu I selected *paragraph...*, *Text Flow*.

In *Breaks* I selected *assign With Page Style* and *set page number*.